# How to create cumulative line chart in Analytics Studio?

Tags: einstein-analytics, charts

According to the release notes Summer '16 ([Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_dashboards_charts.htm)) we should be able to create cumulative line charts in Einstein Analytics.

However, I was not able to find any more documentation about this.
Also looking for the `cumulative line chart` in the dashboard editor did not reveal a way to create such a chart. (They should only be available in Dashboards and not in Lenses according to the release notes.)

Are there any prerequisites for the source step to show the option to make it a cumulative line chart?
Is there some more information on this?

**Edit:** Unfortunately I've misread the release notes - the linked note is referring to Reports & Dashboards in Lightning, meaning that [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/197952/11561) answer is a nice way of achieving the desired functionality in Analytics Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the following 'workaround'.

- Go to dashboard and create a new graph
- Go to compare table
- Clone a column
- Edit the column formula like in the image below
- Now you should have a column containing the cumulative values and you can do with these values what you want

[image]

Comment: Okay, fair enough! Thanks for that! Do you happen to know anything about the 'official feature' for this? Will definitely use your approach if the built-in function disappeared already...

Comment: I do not, unfortunatly.  This is atleast something to get you started :)

Comment: As I've misread / miscategorized the release notes (see original question), I guess, this IS the way you do cumulative charts in Analytics Studio. Thanks!